# Rails grouped_collection_select not working - "undefined method 'map'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a grouped_collection_select in my form however I cannot get it to work.

In my schema I have a table 'sports' with attributes 'name', 'surface' and 'players'.

I would like to group the 'surfaces' by 'name' - here is my attempt:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:surface, Sport.order(:name), :surface, :name, :surface, :surface)  %>
```

This throws error: "undefined method `map'"

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `:surfaces` instead of `:surface` if it's a `has_many` association. Also, would you like to save the `id` or the string? You could change it accordingly.

`<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:surface_id, Sport.order(:name), :surfaces, :name, :id, :name) %>`

Comment: Thanks hassanin I have not explicitly declared a has_many relation anywhere. Instead I just have one model for sports which encompasses name, surface and players...

Comment: When I try your solution i get this error: undefined method `surfaces'

Comment: I think it is because there is a single sport model not a model for sport, surfaces and players - here is the migration: class CreateSports < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :sports do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :surface
      t.integer :players

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Comment: @Laralander yeah that would definitely pose a problem for the `grouped_collection_select` in Rails. You might want to do it manually in HTML (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)